# Is there a way to pull values from the DATE command?

Tags: windows-10

I wanted to make an ascii calendar. I have made a template that I want to put values into, based on the date. The way I wanted to pull the values out of the ’’’date /t’’’ command is like how it’s set up: DDD 00/00/0000. DDD being the day of the week. Is there a way to pull out these values in this manner or in any manner? Sorry for the odd request, still grasping.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this all manually or is there code involved??? :D

Given your reference to the `Date` command and format of its output, your're talking about the `Date` command in `Command Prompt (Cmd.exe)`.

The solution is to use **PowerShell** instead, where the `Get-Date` command returns a .NET `DateTime` value that can be formmatted using [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) formatting strings. Your desired format string would be custom and take the form:

- `"ddd MM/dd/yyyy"` (assuming you're in the U.S.)

The format string can be the arguement of the `ToString()` method applied to a `DateTime` value:

```
PS > (get-date).ToString("ddd MM/dd/yyyy")
Wed 11/02/2022
```

Or used as the format string in a [format item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-item-syntax) used by the [-f (Format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) which uses [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting):

```
'TOday is {0:ddd MM/dd/yyyy}.' -f (Get-Date)
TOday is Wed 11/02/2022.
PS >
```

Answer (score 1):

The `date` command follows your PC's date format. Change your computer short date format to `ddd dd/MM/yyyy`. After the change, the command's output will be displayed as you expect.

[image]

[image]